# Routing from admin area to main index page in razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I want to route from the admin area to the main area of the site, that is, from the Index.cshtml file in the admin area to the Index.cshtml file on the main page.
How can I do that in razor pages with tag helpers?

I was able to routing from main-to-admin area by the following code:

`<a asp-area="Admin" asp-page="/Index">Admin Dashboard</a>`

But how can I have admin-to-main area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add the this:

```
<a asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Main Index</a>
```